# Intermitted behavior with encoded ampersand in URLs

Tags: uri, encode

I am testing how to use data scrape scripts to grab page from Best Buy's page and I generated a link like this:

```
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?_dyncharset=ISO-8859-1&amp;_dynSessConf=1803033044744184095&amp;id=pcat17071&amp;type=page&amp;st=DOTD_2012126b&amp;sc=Global&amp;cp=1&amp;nrp=15&amp;sp=&amp;qp=&amp;list=n&amp;iht=y&amp;usc=All+Categories&amp;ks=960&amp;p=[promotion%2C+synonymns]&amp;pu=defaultusr&amp;pt=1354255201
```

The above link didn't work, I got a `sorry, page not accessible error`.

However, after replacing those ampersands (&) with "&" manually, it worked.

Another link, which also includes encoded `&`, worked.

```
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/PNY+-+32GB+Secure+Digital+High+Capacity+(SDHC)+Class+10+Memory+Card/2300602.p?id=1218318851702&amp;skuId=2300602&amp;st=2300602&amp;cp=1&amp;lp=1
```

Why does it work in the second case?

Comment: i tried to edit my post, 'cause I noticed after it's published, the literal "&amp;" was replaced by "&", then the link works, therefore I was not able to show you guys a broken link. anyway, the problem was that the link looks like "XXX&amp;XXX", and the first link didn't work.

Comment: &amp; is HTML encoding, it will not work for url. In url it can be encoded as %26

Comment: [Removed 'xquery' tag, since the question has no visible connection to XQuery.  Please replace and explain if the question does have some connection to XQuery.]

Answer (score 1):

If the second one works, it's by accident;  whatever happens with these links is completely up to the site.

The links should be encoded with `&amp;` in the html page text, but that's only to allow the `&` to actually be on the page.  The actual URLs should have the literal `&` only.

There is an addendum to one html standard suggesting that urls should use `;` for separating parameters rather than `&`, because of this encoding problem.  The suggestion was pretty much universally ignored (except by CGI.pm, where it annoyed everyone who had to suffer with it)